# group by part of url using regex splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have multiple url's all start with `/api/net`, I want to group by next couple of strings that are separated by / like

```
/api/net/abc/def?key=value
/api/net/c/d?key1=value1
/api/net/j/h?key2=value2
```

I have below regular expression which parses all url's but I explicitly have to specify required in regular expression .

```
| rex field=requestPath "(?<volga>.+?(\/abc\/def)|(\/c\/d)|(\/j\/h).+?)"
```

volga is a named capturing group, I want to do a group by on volga without adding /abc/def, /c/d,/j/h in regular expression so that I would know number of expressions in there instead of hard coding.
There are other expressions I would not know to add, So I want to group by on next 2 words split by / after "net" and do a group by , also ignore rest of the url. Let me know if you did not understand, I could explain more.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, this regex will parse the URL and return the two domains as 'dom1' and 'dom2', respectively.  Then you can group/sort on them.

```
... | rex field=requestPath "\/api\/net\/(?<dom1>[^\/]+)\/(?<dom2>[^\/\?]+)"
| stats values(*) as * by dom1,dom2
```